# How to paginate Eloquent query with orderBy. on join

Tags: mysql, orm, pagination, eloquent, laravel-5

Here i want my top posts of the week or month according to comments of each post.The query is working but i am unable to paginate.Please help!

```
$top = Post::having('created_at', '>=', $time)
        ->selectRaw('posts.*, count(*) as `aggregate`')
        ->join('post_comments', 'posts.id', '=', 'post_comments.post_id')
        ->groupBy('post_id')
        ->orderBy('aggregate', 'desc')
        ->with('post_comments_count')
        ->get();
```

Comment: can anyone help please that's 12:15 a.m here.waiting for response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to make the **paginator** manually while using groupBy as described in [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/pagination#basic-usage)!.

> Note: Currently, pagination operations that use a groupBy statement
>   cannot be executed efficiently by Laravel. If you need to use a
>   groupBy with a paginated result set, it is recommended that you query
>   the database and create a paginator manually.

Answer (score 0):

did you tried the ->paginate() command from Laravel ?

```
$top = Post::having('created_at', '>=', $time)
    ->selectRaw('posts.*, count(*) as `aggregate`')
    ->join('post_comments', 'posts.id', '=', 'post_comments.post_id')
    ->groupBy('post_id')
    ->orderBy('aggregate', 'desc')
    ->with('post_comments_count')
    ->paginate(10);
```

should work fine.
In your blade file you can call the pagination with

```
{!! $top->links() !!}
```

source: [Laravel Pagination](https://laravel.com/docs/master/pagination#basic-usage)

Comment: yes i have and here is error message i am getting:`(SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'created_at' in 'having clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `posts` inner join `post_comments` on `posts`.`id` = `post_comments`.`post_id` where `posts`.`deleted_at` is null and `confirmed` = 0 group by `post_id` having `created_at` >= 2016-04-04))`

Comment: Does your Table 'Posts' have the attribute **created_at** ?

Comment: yes but it says column not found only when i try for paginate

Comment: sorry for trouble and thanks for reply.That's not error in my code.As it is noted in Laravel docs **Note: Currently, pagination operations that use a groupBy statement cannot be executed
efficiently by Laravel. If you need to use a groupBy with a paginated result set, it is
recommended that you query the database and create a paginator manually.**